# using regex for proxypass

Tags: regex, apache

I'm trying to set up a proxy to my corporate environment's ActiveMQ admin pages on our standard http proxy server. I have a rule in place that allows me access to the admin landing page:

`ProxyPass /foobar hostname:8161/admin`

ProxyPassReverse /foobar hostname:8161/admin

However, going to the "queues" page bring me to a different page appended with a unique session ID (admin/queues.jsp;jsessionid=oq37zgvxz4zkwliwdwddyon3), and I would like for this page to be accessible through the same URL as well.

Attempting to add a wildcard (*) at the end of these proxypass rules breaks the redirect. Is there a redirect rule that I need to use in conjunction with this, and how do I get any string to this host to pass through this proxy rule?

Answer (score 3):

There is `ProxyPassMatch` that is regex based, but `ProxyPass` does prefix matching (i.e. a ProxyPass for `/foo` should catch `/foo/bar` too) so your current rule should work anyway.

It may be that the redirection URL doesn't match the reverse rule for some reason. I have to admit I've never managed to get a `ProxyPass` to Tomcat to work correctly when the front and back end context paths differ, so my advice would be to deploy the back end app at `hostname:8161/foobar` instead of `/admin` if that's an option.